# Euler conjecture for 514 case

Tags: diophantine-equations

I was trying to find counterexamples for the Euler conjecture for fifth power, but I couldn't find any aside from $27^5+84^5+110^5+133^5=144^5.$ Python script finds the first solution using a brute force approach in a second. It takes one day to check that there are no solutions below 1000 aside from multiples of the first solution.

In case of $a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4$ one can use modular arithmetic because $(n^4)\mod5$ guarantees that $a\mod5=0, b\mod 5=0, c\mod5=1$ and $d\mod5=1,$ allowing aggressive pruning. There are no such modulo for fifth power. One of the best cases $(x^5 \mod 11)$ yields [ 0  1 10  1  1  1 10 10 10  1 10], allowing to speed up the computation by a factor of $257,$ which isn't much.

What other tricks can be used to speed up the computation? Are there any other solutions known?

Comment: cf. [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation5thPowers.html) and ref's there; e.g., $85282^5+28969^5+3183^5+55^5=85359^5$

Comment: Also see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/020), according to which the solutions you and J.W. Tanner mentioned were the only ones known (up to multiples) with positive entries, as of 2009.

Comment: Looking modulo 31 would cut the candidates down by another factor of 14.6 or so.

Comment: [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4761287/4781) on the (5,1,4) equation.